# Add custom rule to code analyser for core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, code-analysis, fxcop

I am new to code analyser using nuget package.
I have installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers in my code and now i want to add some custom rules.
Please share some example

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rule set to your project and that can be done in a few different ways. For example, if you modify a rule a rule set file will be added to the project.

[image]

You can then open the file and modify add/remove rulesets

[image]

You can also add a new item, and select rule set

[image]

The rule set file is referenced in the project file like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>ExampleCoreApp.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>ExampleCoreApp.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264897.aspx) for more information